# Don't load the modal if the the value is empty onload

Tags: javascript, html

I want to  show modal only after form gets submitted.but It's loading at starting.
Here is my html code

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Dear User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Please note down your respective ID's</p>
          <p id="ucid">Client ID:<s:property value="ucid"/></p>
          <p>Broker ID:<s:property value="ubid"/></p>
          <p>Developer ID:<s:property value="udid"/></p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and here is Javascript

```
function myFunction(){
        if ($('#ucid').val()=='') {
            $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        }else{
         $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
        }
```

though i tried above function to hide that.but its not working.please help me out.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.text()` method to get value from `p` DOM element.

```
if ($('#ucid').text()=='') {
     $("#myModal").modal("hide");
}else{
     $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
}
```

Comment: actually I am setting value inside that <s:property> and at the very starting of the app value is empty

Comment: @Parikshit, Please accept answer in order to help other people.